# Возможно ли сделать бесконечный box-shadow?

Tags: css, css3

Можно сделать тень с фиксированным отступом, и фиксированной высоты, например отступ 100px и высота самого дива, возможно ли сделать бесконечную тень вниз без отступа? Внешний и внутренний див может быть любой высоты.

Хочу получить такой результат:

[image: a busy cat]

Чтобы тень была сплошная от края элемента до самого низа страницы

```css
.wrapper{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
}
.inner{
  padding: 8px 10px 3px 35px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #6288cf;
  box-shadow:0 100px 0 #6288cf;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не понимаю ваш вопрос в том смысле, что не представляю как вы хотите чтобы выглядел результат. Можете просто задать для нужной величины какое-то огромное значение, допустим `99999px`. И это будет подобно бесконечности.

Comment: @vadim-ovchinnikov добавила изображение с желаемым результатом. Идея такая - элемент встречается в любом месте на странице и отбрасывает тень до самого ее края, образовывая как бы столбец, но который не зависит от других элементов и от высоты страницы.

Comment: @Grundy, раз уж переносишь картинку, то загрузи её сюда.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тутошный загрузчик сказал что формат файла не поддерживается, я поэтому просто разметку поправил

Comment: @Grundy, ну так правой кнопкой и copy image, а тут вставляешь. А то у меня joxi.net заболокирован :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этого эффекта можно добиться при помощи псевдоэлементов. В примере используется `::after`, ему достаточно задать `height: 99999px` и добавить обертке (в данном случае `body`) `overflow: hidden`.

```css
*, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: calc(100% + 1px);
  content: '';
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 99999px;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Comment: а что, если страница будет длиннее 99999px? :)

Answer (score 2):

Задавайте тень в единицах зависящих от высоты экрана — `vh`. У тени есть несколько параметров вам надо задавать вертикальное расположение и распространение. Чтобы тень занимала весь низ и по в экран нужно задать тень так: `box-shadow: 0 50vh 0 50vh red;`, где вместо `red` указывайте нyжный цвет. Небесполезно будет также для `body` или нужного контейнера задать `overflow: hidden;`.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.inner {
  padding: 8px 10px 3px 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #6288cf;
  box-shadow: 0 50vh 0 50vh red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">...</div>
</div>
```

Также можете вместо `50vh` использовать `calc(50vh - 10px)`, где вместо `10px` можете использовать нужное количество пикселей.

Comment: Судя по результату, тень распространяется не только вниз, но и везде вообще.

Comment: Нет, она занимает чётко величину экрана. Это из-за высоты контейнера `300px`.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что тень распространяется также влево и вправо, а автору вопроса необходимо распространение тени только вниз.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Это правда, но я не знаю, что можно с этим сделать, не меняя того, что это тень. Может тогда кому-то другому может пригодится мой ответ.